# URL encoded POST bad practice?

Tags: rest

I am (just for fun) trying to implement a High Score web-service. I would like it be compatible with REST principles. I want to be able to add a new highscore using url parameters like this `http://mydomain.com/hs/add&name=John&score=987`. According to REST this must be done using a POST request. Which leads to empty POST request with all data contained in the URL parameters. Would this be considered a bad practice?

**Update**
Security is currently not a big concern.

Comment: It doesn't really matter where you place the variables... whether in a GET, a GET-like POST or a real POST, a smart user can manipulate the highscores in a few minutes. Look into some forms of encryption (public-key; RSA?) for a (practically) safe solution.

Comment: You probably mean `http://mydomain.com/hs/add?name=John&score=987`, see section 3.3 of RFC 1738: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The common way to do it would be to send a POST to `http://mydomain.com/hs/add` with the content:

`name=John&score=987` (for simple urlencoded data, would be different for e.g. multipart encoded data; the format of the POST request body is arbitrary and outside of the scope of REST recommendations – it could even be arbitrary encrypted data, as others have suggested).

A GET request for adding a new highscore would not only be a violation of REST principles, but also a violation of [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), which requires GET requests to be idempotent.

**EDIT**

> Is it bad practice to pass data in the query string and post an empty body?

Yes. The URL should describe the resource that's being subjected to the action described by the HTTP method. Hence, probably the best option would be to have `http://mydomain.com/hs` as an URL and let the body completely describe the action.

The query string could possibly be used to further qualify requests without a body, e.g.:

`http://mydomain.com/hs?period=lastmonth` (GET)

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question.  If I'm reading it correct, the question was: Is it bad practice to pass data in the query string and post an empty body?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and helpful answer (especially the edit).

Answer (score 2):

You use a question mark before the parameters, so it would be: `http://mydomain.com/hs/add?name=John&score=987`. However, the idea is that the URL should be the name of the resource, and the request method should decide what to do.

So, the correct URL would be just `http://mydomain.com/hs`, and you would send the parameters in the POST data instead. As it's a POST request, it will add data to the resource.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you don't like, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, using url parameters in a POST is not bad practice as far as REST is concerned.  This seems to be a perfectly valid approach to me.

From a aesthetics perspective I would suggest an url such as

```
 POST http://mydomain.com/highscores?name=John&score=987
```

Comment: Querystring params for your identifier (rather than in the request body) isn't right at all...

Comment: @Amalgovinus Based on what evidence? [RFC3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.4) clearly states that a query string is part of the identifier of the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Very bad..the user can manipulate the score. You should apply some sort of encryption, even if it's simple, before submitting the score through the querystring

Comment: Using a true POST would only make it marginally more difficult. The real solution may be a kind of encryption, but that's not what the user is asking.

Answer (score 0):

GET should be utilized when obtaining data. When adding or manipulating data, you should always use POST.

That way a user won't:

- Accidentally go to the url again and render all of your data dirty
- Purposefully alter your database

Answer (score 0):

Use POST request to prevent following situation:

- User logs-in
- Web browser saves authentication information between session
- User receives for example an email with HTML contains tag like 
  < img src='http://mydomain.com/hs/add?name=John&score=987' ... />
- Mail client tries to download the image, automatically uses credentials stored in web browser, and adds or deletes information from/to your system silently.